# On logout as admin, PHP code from node pages is executed.

Tags: 6, users

When I log out from site as Admin, PHP code in the node pages is being executed.
For testing, I had put *node access rebuild* function in one of pages and the site went slow after that. When I checked in the xdebug profiler scripts, I came across this `eval()` call.
Is it the default functionality or is it some of my code that has affected this?

Comment: What php code is being executed?  In this case, I imagine the answer is "no", but you can check this easily yourself-- install a fresh copy of Drupal 6 and make a quick "dummy" site to see if the code is present/executing there as well.

Comment: In general, it should not be needed to put PHP code in nodes. Ever. Not even for testing. Try if the problem persists if you move your custom code to a module, where it belongs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the page you are referring is a node page, then the node could be using the PHP input format, and in that case the node body would be passed to `eval()` through [drupal_eval()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_eval/6).
If the page is a view page, the Views module allows the administrator users to enter PHP code that is executed, through `drupal_eval()`, in specific circumstances.

[image: screenshot]

In both the cases, a block visible in the page could be using PHP code to set it block visibility.

[image: screenshot]

There could be other modules that call `drupal_eval()`. Those modules pass to `drupal_eval()` code that users with the right permission enter in the module's settings; if you have one of those modules, you should remember ending PHP code in a text area.

Comment: Ok , is there any way to prevent this ? what if some publicly accessible page in PHP format has system commands in it , i know its a big mistake to make it PHP format , but still evaluating PHP code unknowingly is not good.

Comment: The code is input entered from users. Look at the setting pages used from the modules, and see if there is any PHP code. There isn't any way to prevent it, if not changing the settings.